node-pty installation on server is showing npm error code -1
Whenever I am doing
npm i node-pty

it is giving me this error
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.8.1
2 info using node@v20.14.0
3 silly config load:file:C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc
4 silly config load:file:D:\Coding\vstart0.1.0\server\.npmrc
5 silly config load:file:C:\Users\DELL\.npmrc
6 silly config load:file:C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
7 verbose title npm i node-pty
8 verbose argv "i" "node-pty"
9 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-08T08_40_17_846Z-
10 verbose logfile C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-08T08_40_17_846Z-debug-0.log
11 silly packumentCache heap:2197815296 maxSize:549453824 maxEntrySize:274726912
12 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
13 silly logfile done cleaning log files
14 silly idealTree buildDeps
15 silly fetch manifest node-pty@*
16 silly packumentCache full:https://registry.npmjs.org/node-pty cache-miss
17 verbose shrinkwrap failed to load node_modules/.package-lock.json out of date, updated: node_modules
18 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-pty 1259ms (cache revalidated)
19 silly packumentCache full:https://registry.npmjs.org/node-pty set size:1107473 disposed:false
20 silly placeDep ROOT node-pty@1.0.0 OK for: server@1.0.0 want: *
21 silly fetch manifest nan@^2.17.0
22 silly packumentCache full:https://registry.npmjs.org/nan cache-miss
23 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan 73ms (cache revalidated)
24 silly packumentCache full:https://registry.npmjs.org/nan set size:213277 disposed:false
25 silly placeDep ROOT nan@2.20.0 OK for: node-pty@1.0.0 want: ^2.17.0
26 silly reify moves {}
27 silly audit bulk request {
27 silly audit   '@socket.io/component-emitter': [ '3.1.2' ],
27 silly audit   '@types/cookie': [ '0.4.1' ],
27 silly audit   '@types/cors': [ '2.8.17' ],
27 silly audit   '@types/node': [ '20.14.10' ],
27 silly audit   accepts: [ '1.3.8' ],
27 silly audit   'array-flatten': [ '1.1.1' ],
27 silly audit   base64id: [ '2.0.0' ],
27 silly audit   'body-parser': [ '1.20.2' ],
27 silly audit   bytes: [ '3.1.2' ],
27 silly audit   'call-bind': [ '1.0.7' ],
27 silly audit   'content-disposition': [ '0.5.4' ],
27 silly audit   'content-type': [ '1.0.5' ],
27 silly audit   cookie: [ '0.6.0', '0.4.2' ],
27 silly audit   'cookie-signature': [ '1.0.6' ],
27 silly audit   cors: [ '2.8.5' ],
27 silly audit   debug: [ '2.6.9', '4.3.5' ],
27 silly audit   'define-data-property': [ '1.1.4' ],
27 silly audit   depd: [ '2.0.0' ],
27 silly audit   destroy: [ '1.2.0' ],
27 silly audit   'ee-first': [ '1.1.1' ],
27 silly audit   encodeurl: [ '1.0.2' ],
27 silly audit   'engine.io': [ '6.5.5' ],
27 silly audit   'engine.io-parser': [ '5.2.2' ],
27 silly audit   ms: [ '2.1.2', '2.0.0', '2.1.3' ],
27 silly audit   'es-define-property': [ '1.0.0' ],
27 silly audit   'es-errors': [ '1.3.0' ],
27 silly audit   'escape-html': [ '1.0.3' ],
27 silly audit   etag: [ '1.8.1' ],
27 silly audit   express: [ '4.19.2' ],
27 silly audit   finalhandler: [ '1.2.0' ],
27 silly audit   forwarded: [ '0.2.0' ],
27 silly audit   fresh: [ '0.5.2' ],
27 silly audit   'function-bind': [ '1.1.2' ],
27 silly audit   'get-intrinsic': [ '1.2.4' ],
27 silly audit   gopd: [ '1.0.1' ],
27 silly audit   'has-property-descriptors': [ '1.0.2' ],
27 silly audit   'has-proto': [ '1.0.3' ],
27 silly audit   'has-symbols': [ '1.0.3' ],
27 silly audit   hasown: [ '2.0.2' ],
27 silly audit   'http-errors': [ '2.0.0' ],
27 silly audit   'iconv-lite': [ '0.4.24' ],
27 silly audit   inherits: [ '2.0.4' ],
27 silly audit   'ipaddr.js': [ '1.9.1' ],
27 silly audit   'media-typer': [ '0.3.0' ],
27 silly audit   'merge-descriptors': [ '1.0.1' ],
27 silly audit   methods: [ '1.1.2' ],
27 silly audit   mime: [ '1.6.0' ],
27 silly audit   'mime-db': [ '1.52.0' ],
27 silly audit   'mime-types': [ '2.1.35' ],
27 silly audit   negotiator: [ '0.6.3' ],
27 silly audit   'object-assign': [ '4.1.1' ],
27 silly audit   'object-inspect': [ '1.13.2' ],
27 silly audit   'on-finished': [ '2.4.1' ],
27 silly audit   parseurl: [ '1.3.3' ],
27 silly audit   'path-to-regexp': [ '0.1.7' ],
27 silly audit   'proxy-addr': [ '2.0.7' ],
27 silly audit   qs: [ '6.11.0' ],
27 silly audit   'range-parser': [ '1.2.1' ],
27 silly audit   'raw-body': [ '2.5.2' ],
27 silly audit   'safe-buffer': [ '5.2.1' ],
27 silly audit   'safer-buffer': [ '2.1.2' ],
27 silly audit   send: [ '0.18.0' ],
27 silly audit   'serve-static': [ '1.15.0' ],
27 silly audit   'set-function-length': [ '1.2.2' ],
27 silly audit   setprototypeof: [ '1.2.0' ],
27 silly audit   'side-channel': [ '1.0.6' ],
27 silly audit   'socket.io': [ '4.7.5' ],
27 silly audit   'socket.io-adapter': [ '2.5.5' ],
27 silly audit   'socket.io-parser': [ '4.2.4' ],
27 silly audit   statuses: [ '2.0.1' ],
27 silly audit   toidentifier: [ '1.0.1' ],
27 silly audit   'type-is': [ '1.6.18' ],
27 silly audit   'undici-types': [ '5.26.5' ],
27 silly audit   unpipe: [ '1.0.0' ],
27 silly audit   'utils-merge': [ '1.0.1' ],
27 silly audit   vary: [ '1.1.2' ],
27 silly audit   ws: [ '8.17.1' ],
27 silly audit   'node-pty': [ '1.0.0' ],
27 silly audit   nan: [ '2.20.0' ]
27 silly audit }
28 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 288ms
29 silly audit report {}
30 info run node-pty@1.0.0 install node_modules/node-pty node-gyp rebuild
31 info run node-pty@1.0.0 install { code: 1, signal: null }
32 verbose stack Error: command failed
32 verbose stack     at promiseSpawn (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:22:22)
32 verbose stack     at spawnWithShell (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:124:10)
32 verbose stack     at promiseSpawn (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:12:12)
32 verbose stack     at runScriptPkg (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\lib\run-script-pkg.js:77:13)
32 verbose stack     at runScript (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\lib\run-script.js:9:12)
32 verbose stack     at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\rebuild.js:329:17
32 verbose stack     at run (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-call-limit\dist\commonjs\index.js:67:22)
32 verbose stack     at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-call-limit\dist\commonjs\index.js:84:9
32 verbose stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
32 verbose stack     at callLimit (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-call-limit\dist\commonjs\index.js:35:69)
33 verbose pkgid node-pty@1.0.0
34 error code 1
35 error path D:\Coding\vstart0.1.0\server\node_modules\node-pty
36 error command failed
37 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
38 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
38 error gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
38 error gyp info using node@20.14.0 | win32 | x64
38 error gyp ERR! find Python 
38 error gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
38 error gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - executable path is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - executable path is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - executable path is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python311-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python311-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python311-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python311-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python310-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python310-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
38 error gyp ERR! find Python 
38 error gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
38 error gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
38 error gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
38 error gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
38 error gyp ERR! find Python (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
38 error gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
38 error gyp ERR! find Python npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
38 error gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
38 error gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
38 error gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
38 error gyp ERR! find Python 
38 error gyp ERR! configure error 
38 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
38 error gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:306:11)
38 error gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.findPython (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:164:17)
38 error gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
38 error gyp ERR! stack at async configure (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:27:18)
38 error gyp ERR! stack at async run (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js:81:18)
38 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
38 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
38 error gyp ERR! cwd D:\Coding\vstart0.1.0\server\node_modules\node-pty
38 error gyp ERR! node -v v20.14.0
38 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
38 error gyp ERR! not ok
39 silly unfinished npm timer reify 1720428019342
40 silly unfinished npm timer reify:build 1720428022749
41 silly unfinished npm timer build 1720428022750
42 silly unfinished npm timer build:deps 1720428022751
43 silly unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1720428022758
44 silly unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/node-pty 1720428022760
45 verbose cwd D:\Coding\vstart0.1.0\server
46 verbose os Windows_NT 10.0.19045
47 verbose node v20.14.0
48 verbose npm  v10.8.1
49 verbose exit 1
50 verbose code 1
51 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-08T08_40_17_846Z-debug-0.log


I tried upgrading node application, reinstalling node-gyp installing python but all 3 didnt work

It doesn't look like it can find whatever python version you installed.  Where did you install it?

@ewokx I installed it in the default path...

Did you try with 64bit python ?
